# How to call an external command in Gimp Plugin?

Tags: shell, plugins, imagemagick, gimp, script-fu

How to use an external command to make an edit of pic in the gimp and then return the result to the stage in a plugin or script.

Example in shell script.:

magick label.gif +matte 
( +clone  -shade 110x90 -normalize -negate +clone  -compose Plus -composite ) 
( -clone 0 -shade 110x50 -normalize -channel BG -fx 0 +channel -matte ) 
-delete 0 +swap  -compose Multiply -

The command above (imagemagick app) create a gif and i want put back in gimp stage. May be other simple option or application, but i need of return the edited back to gimp. Python, script fu? Thanks so much.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMfD9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`shellout.py` Gimp plugin floating around](https://pastebin.com/sAkzSMq7) from which you can borrow code. Typically:

- you export the layer to a temp file (if you work on the whole image, you likely have to do a `pdb.gimp_layer_new_from_visible()`)
- call the executable with `subprocess.Popen()` and a list of arguments
- load the result as a new layer with `pdb.gimp_file_load_layer()`

Comment: Thanks ; -) Help me a lot. I am using shellout.py. Its a small but deep trace in sand. 
https://github.com/oldfatcrab/Mac-GIMP-Nik/blob/master/ShellOut.py

Comment: If that worked then consider marking the answer as accepted (check mark icon next to the votes). It helps others finding answers to similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

If GIMP will take stdin, then pipe from ImageMagick to GIMP using the GIMP XCF file format.

```
magick label.gif +matte 
( +clone -shade 110x90 -normalize -negate +clone -compose Plus -composite ) 
( -clone 0 -shade 110x50 -normalize -channel BG -fx 0 +channel -matte ) 
-delete 0 +swap -compose Multiply XCF:- | GIMP -
```

Comment: Thank you. Its seem me good to export from imagemagick into gimp... I think thats good for imagemagick primary use and posterior gimp edition.